# What to use in iOS programming for displaying person and 4 properties

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

I want to make simple iOS app. From the list - 300 persons you select one person based on his name ( names will be different ) and then you see 4 different atributes of this person. I see it as UITable view with one Label and 4 cells with attributes. What is common way to keep all this data - names and attributes?  It will be around 1200 records. Should I use NSArray , or NSDictionary ? Name could be the key to corresponding attributes. Maybe someone could tip on some tutorial? Many thanks!

Comment: I'd say go with an array of dictionaries

Answer (score 1):

As @KaanDedeoglu said, go with an NSArray of NSDictionaries. It's easiest to use an array to display the data in a table view, and in the cell configuration method, you can easily access the NSDictionaries inside of the array. [This](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/12/10/implementing-uitableview-sections-from-an-nsarray-of-nsdictionary-objects/) should show you how to do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary of dictionaries will give you better performance than an array of dictionaries. (faster access due to the set of keys being indexed, you will avoid "for" loops for iterations and use objectForKey: instead". In my opinion this approach is better for larger sets of data). 
Downside for this approach: ordering will not be preserved, however you can do the sorting yourself before displaying items (ex. get all keys, sort them alphabetically, then start displaying objects for each key in the sorted keys array, etc. Implementation may vary depending on your needs).